# Permission denied error when executing .py file with Geany IDE (Raspberry Pi Raspbian)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, virtualenv, raspbian, geany

I configured a python3 virtual env and added the path to the execute Build Command of Geany.
Now if I try to execute the .py file with Geany I get the following error:

```
Wi-Fi is currently blocked by rfkill.
Use raspi-config to set the country before use.

/tmp/geany_run_script_5J3UG0.sh: 7: /tmp/geany_run_script_5J3UG0.sh: /home/pi/PyProjekte/pytorchenv1/bin: Permission denied


------------------
(program exited with code: 126)
```

I have already tried the command:
`chmod +x ~/PyProjekte/pytorchenv1/bin`
and:
`chmod +x /tmp/geany_run_script_5J3UG0.sh`
but if I try to chmod the .sh file it tells me that the .sh file is not available

I hope you can help me with that.
If I execute the .py file manually with the command line within the virtual env it executes normally but I would like to be able to execute it from Geany.

This is what I have added to the Execute Command in Geany:
`/home/pi/PyProjekte/pytorchenv1/bin "%f"`

Comment: Is `/home/pi/PyProjekte/pytorchenv1/bin` the directory in which your .py file is located?

Comment: @DavidYockey no it's just the bin directory for my virtual environment. My .py file is located in a sub directory of /home/pi/PyProjekte/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only speculate, but it may be of some help... Given a .py file, my Geany installation shows `python "%f"` as the default entry for the Execute command; perhaps providing the full path to `python` or `python3` within your virtual environment might work. If that doesn't work or you're still getting a permission error, you might try installing Geany within the virtual env (if that's even possible; I don't know) and running it from there to get around permission issues.